# Flowplayer video won't go fullscreen in ie11

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

Playing around with flowplayer videos, and I can't seem to managed to get the video to go full screen in IE11 . It works just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE11 . I've tested and seen that flowplayer videos will go fullscreen in IE11 when I open the demos on flowplayers website. Any idea what I might have done wrong?

My site : http://clients.geantduweb.ca/index.php?tmpl=flowplayer&video_id=1

A flowplayer hosted demo: https://flowplayer.org/standalone/skins/minimal.html

Is there a problem with my configurations, a basic css problem or something else I managed to mess up?